# Google calendar API with a server side account node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api

The title pretty much sums it up.

I'm sorry for asking this question here but i have been going around and around in circles for about 2h now trying to figure out if it is possible to access a calendar's events (simple get, read-only) without the user having to login to a google account? 
I am trying to display the events of one calendar to use as an internal thing. But i want this to work without necessarily asking the user to log-in manually.

I have a service account set-up, but for the life of me cannot figure out an example in javascript where this works. And i'm wondering if it is even possible in JS. I know it is possible in java and php. But no examples using javascript seem to exist.

I also saw a few similar cases on stackOverflow, but those cases were looking for refresh tokens. I would like to abstract all authentication from the user.

So, is this possible in javascript?

(Angular.js client-side/Node.js server-side)

**Edit for TL;DR**

I want to fetch and display events from a google calendar from a node.js server without **ANY** user intervention. Is this possible?

Comment: This seems pretty simple so maybe I'm not getting it. But Google Apps Calendar has a Node API library. If you just publish the Calendar you're looking to read, you can easily access it with that API. Why bother with a user account?

Comment: yes, depending on the publish settings of the calendar.

Comment: ex: http://tinyurl.com/kkjrxbd (`https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/#h=select+*+from+csv+where+url%3D'https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fcalendar%2Fical%2Fkrannertcenter%2540mac.com%2Fpublic%2Fbasic.ics'+`)

Comment: @Dominick ... Well now i just feel ridiculously stupid having spent so much time trying to mess around with their Oauth BS... Will try the node package and see how that turns out. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Dominick Well... that was a lot of time wasted for nothing. Let me reprhase the question easily. Check the TL;DR edit. Your solution does not seem to help me whatsoever on that front.

Comment: I have never seen anyone get a service account to work with JavaScript.  This is probably due to security issues,  personally I wonder if it may even be against the current terms of service.   Service accounts are for server sided languages only.    Option set the calendar public and try and access it using a public access key (never tried it but it should work in theory)

Answer (score 1):

HAHA! I found something that [works](https://github.com/extrabacon/google-oauth-jwt).

Install it, create google service-account, download the .p12, convert, enter the info and you're good. Detailed on his github. Calendar stays "private" (only shared to the service account), no user intervention is necessary and it fetches the data fine

(Mostly... Having a problem deploying my js code on a different machine but it works fine on the Windows I used for testing and it's probably a mistake on my part.)